# Using sqlite3 with Ruby, is there a way to read each row as a hash instead of array?

Tags: ruby, sqlite3-ruby

I am using sqlite3 as follows:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.open "data.db"

stm = db.prepare "SELECT * FROM COMPANIES"
rs = stm.execute

while (row = rs.next) do
    name = row[1]
```

that is, the row is an array instead of a hash. Is there a way to read it as a hash, so that

```
row[:name]
row[:address]
```

is the data. That's because in the future, if the table has a different order of columns, `row[3]` may become `row[5]`, so `row[:address]` is much more definite.

Comment: Rather than use the SQLite gem, I'd recommend one of the ORMs that help insulate you from a DBM-specific language. SQLite is nice, but if your DB needs grow having to rewrite all your calls for a different DBM is a major pain. I like [Sequel](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) because it's very agnostic and very capable. https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html is a good overview.

Answer (score 5):

There's [`results_as_hash`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3%2FDatabase:results_as_hash) setter to get this behavior:

```
db = SQLite3::Databse.open 'data.db'
db.results_as_hash = true
# ...
```

Comment: works great. I suppose it has to be `row["NAME"]` and can't be made to `row[:NAME]`?